# How do I use unison to synchronize only dotfiles and dotfolders?

Tags: dotfiles, unison

I would like to synchronize only files and folders that start with a dot in my home folder.

More specifically, I only want to synchronize the files and folders listed by:

```
ls -ld ~/.[^.]*
```

Unison command line I tried:

```
unison /home/username /backup/dotfiles -ui text -perms 0 -ignorenot 'Regex .[!.]*' -ignore 'Regex *[!.]'
```

gives the error:

```
Malformed pattern "Regex *[!.]".
```

This is a simplified example, and it would be reasonable to do this with rsync instead, but I would like to use unison because in my real use case I need bidirectional sync.

Answer (score 3):

The regex syntax you're looking for is

```
"^.[^.]*"
```